# Finding contours after drawing them

Tags: opencv

I used a random image from internet containing 4 circles.  [But, the opencv segmentation code detects 307 contours. However, I want to detect only 4 circles. So I tried to blur the image to remove noise. But, still no help.
Then I used the following code.

```
Mat ContourOutline = Mat::zeros(cannyEdges.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Area of contour " << i << "=" << contourArea(contours[i])<<"\n";
        Scalar color = Scalar(0,0,255);
        drawContours(ContourOutline, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }
```

This produced a perfect image.![drawn 4 circles][3] Now, I want run the find contours code on this image. But, Visual Studio throws an unhandled exception. What should I do to detect the four circles?

Comment: findContours assumes a binary image as input, your ContourOutline is BGR color image.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that. It works now.

Comment: nice to hear. I'll write an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You create `ContourOutline` as a `CV_8UC3` element matrix, which (probably) means to be a `BGR` color image, but `findContours` uses binary images of type `CV_8UC1` as input.

Try this code:

```
Mat ContourOutline = Mat::zeros(cannyEdges.size(), CV_8UC1);
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "Area of contour " << i << "=" << contourArea(contours[i])<<"\n";
    Scalar color = Scalar(255);
    drawContours(ContourOutline, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
}
```